# How does jQuery achieve making $ an alias for the jQuery function?

Tags: jquery

I’m having a little trouble wrapping my head around the $ sign being an alias for the jQuery function, particularly in a plugin. Can you explain how jQuery achieves this aliasing: how does it define '$' to be an alias for the jQuery function? That's the first question.

Secondly, can you explain how/why the following code works to map '$' to the jQuery function in a plugin's definition and why if you don't do this, your plugin could collide with other libraries that might use the dollar sign?

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
        // Do your awesome plugin stuff here
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A function, like any object in javascript, can be assigned to a variable.  This variable can have any name (that follows the JS variable naming rules).  "$" satisfies the naming rules, so the jQuery function is aliased to "$" for brevity.  Consider the following example:

```
var myFn = function() { alert('myFunc'); };
var $ = myFn;

$();
// alerts 'myFunc'
```

Comment: For clarity, this example is stand-alone - that is, don't load jQuery first and expect anything good to come of it.

Comment: Unless you really like alerting 'myFunc'

Answer (score 27):

It simply declares a variable. See [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js)

jQuery itself is a large self executing function. This means that it declares a function and then runs it. Inside the function it declares the local `jQuery` object which is a function.

It will then right at the end of it set `window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery`

This is setting both `window.jQuery` and `window.$` to the local `jQuery` object. We can set global variables by making them properties of the `window` object.

Now both `window.jQuery` and `window.$` both point at `jQuery` since objects are passed by reference.

```
var jQuery = (function() {

    var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
        ...
    };

    ...

    return (window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery);

}());
```

it actaully declares jQuery twice for a small efficiency gain since the when looking for the variable it doesn't have to look upwards into an extra outer function.

You can use two assignments like that because `(var a = b) === b`

As others have mentioned the fact that `$` is a legimate variable name and that functions are first class objects, thus we can treat them as objects also helps to make this possible.

Comment: And '$' is a legitimate identifier in javascript.

Comment: +1 for the explanation of how jQuery is actually declared, and therefore how it works (allowing method chaining, for example)

Answer (score 4):

Exact code (from jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js):

```
// Expose jQuery to the global object
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

Answer (score 3):

Objects in JavaScript, and thus jQuery, are functions. You could define your own JS library by creating a function with other functions assigned to attributes of this single function:

```
myLibrary = function() {
    this.myLibraryFunction = function() {
        ...
    };
};

new myLibrary().myLibraryFunction();
```

In a similar way jQuery does this with a function named `jQuery`, instead of `myLibrary` in the above example.

### Creating Aliases

Creating aliases (or references) is possible because JavaScript allows references to functions to be passed around without having to actually call the function. For example:

```
new myLibrary().myLibraryFunction();
```

calls your library function, however omitting the parentheses allows you to deal with a reference to that function:

```
var f = new myLibrary().myLibraryFunction;
```

You can then call the references you have stored, rather than the original by putting the parentheses back:

```
var f = new myLibrary().myLibraryFunction;
f();
```

In the same way jQuery can store a reference to the `jQuery` function in another variable named `$`:

```
var $ = jQuery;
```

You can see this concept used [in the jQuery source code on github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L1054).

Comment: "Objects in JavaScript, and thus jQuery are functions" Please do make that the other way round. `myLibrary.myLibraryFunction();` that isn't valid code if used together with the example. your myLibraryFunction is just declaring a local function as a variable. It isn't accesible outside

Comment: The answer is amended. However "Objects in JavaScript, and thus jQuery are functions" makes sense either way round.

Comment: var obj = {};
console.log(typeof obj); // prints 'object'

Comment: 1. Objects in javascript are not functions. Functions are objects though. All the syntax is wrong. Please test it before posting it.

Comment: The syntax is correct and tested, you are correct with regard to functions being objects, but the point I was making was that jQuery creates its jQuery objects using a function in this way.