# What difference between $ and $() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

According to jQuery API I see that `$()` is collection of matched elements. But what is `$` ? Example from `imagesLoaded` library below.

```
if ( $ ) {
  $.fn.imagesLoaded = function( options, callback ) {
    var instance = new ImagesLoaded( this, options, callback );
    return instance.jqDeferred.promise( $(this) );
  };
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797956/how-does-jquery-achieve-making-an-alias-for-the-jquery-function

Comment: The question is not, "what is `$`", the question is, what is the difference between `$` and `$()`.

Comment: The code shown could have several possible results: (1) if `$` has not been defined it'll give a `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` and execution will not continue after the `if`; (2) if `$` has been defined but has a falsy value the code inside the `{}` will not be executed; (3) if `$` has a truthy value but is not `jQuery` it'll probably give some kind of type error (unless `$` is an object that already has a `fn` property that is also an object); (4) if `$` exists as an alias for `jQuery` the code will work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the jquery's code:

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

so *$* is actually a pointer to *jQuery* global object.

Answer (score 1):

`$` is referencing the `jQuery Object`, like an alias.

Objects do have constructors.

Calling `$('#test');` results in `jQuery('#test');`

See this for constructor explanation: [Constructors in JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114024/constructors-in-javascript-objects)

From the jQuery Source @github:

```
jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$` is a reference to the jQuery function (in your case), so this condition just checks whether a variable or function named `$` evalutes to *true*.

Example:

```
function test() {
  // do something
}

if (test) {
}
```

The expression `test` references the function.

Comment: Note that `if (variableName) {` is _not_ the correct way to test whether a variable exists because if it doesn't exist you get a `ReferenceError: variableName is not defined`.

Comment: @nnnnnn You're right, therefore I put "exists" in double quotes. I've just rephrased it ;) It should be right, now.