# Responsive FB Page Plug-In with auto browser refresh JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I am trying to embed on my site a plug-in to my Facebook Page with fully responsive behavior. Basically, I just want its width to change at different browser sizes; 480px when the browser is 480 or narrower; 250px when 481 < browser < 731, and 300px when browser is 731 or wider.

I realize that this question [has been asked here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429296/responsive-width-facebook-page-plugin#29503539), but previous answers either no longer work thanks to FB changes, or require that the user refresh their browser window. But on [this blog post](https://www.mugo.ca/Blog/How-to-make-the-Facebook-Page-Plugin-fully-responsive) I have found an **actual example** of a fully-functioning responsive FB Page plug-in; it changes size and other characteristics on-the-fly as the browser window is resized.

The blog post mentions the JavaScript they use, and a link to the site where you can see it in play. But they do not offer a stripped-down summary of all the CSS and HTML involved, and the code on their site is a bit complicated for my newbie eyes. I've tried adding their JavaScript to my site, but for some reason it's not working for me. As you change the browser width, my DIV #fbsection adjusts its width just fine, but the DIV .fb-page inside it will only change if you refresh.

I made my site in Dreamweaver CS 6 using their responsive template, and it incorporates their style sheet **boilerplate.css** and JavaScript **respond.min.js**. The relevant code is as follows:

(from the HTML document)

```
    <link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="bluedolphin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="respond.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
       <div id="fb-root"></div>
            <script>(function(d, s, id) {
              var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
              if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
              js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
              js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10";
              fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));



        $(window).on('resize', function() {


setTimeout(function(){CMSSpace.changeFBPagePlugin()}, 500);
});

$(window).on('load', function() {
   setTimeout(function(){CMSSpace.changeFBPagePlugin()}, 1500);
});

CMSSpace.changeFBPagePlugin = function () {
   //getting parent box width
   var container_width = (Number($('.fb-column').width()) - Number($('.fb-column').css('padding-left').replace("px", ""))).toFixed(0);
   //getting parent box height
   var container_height = (Number($('.fb-column').height()) - (Number($('.fb-column-header').height()) + Number($('.fb-column-   header').css('margin-bottom').replace("px", "")) + Number(($('.fb-column').css('padding-top').replace("px", "")*2)))).toFixed(0);
   if (!isNaN(container_width) && !isNaN(container_height)) {
      $(".fb-page").attr("data-width", container_width).attr("data-height", container_height);
   }
   if (typeof FB !== 'undefined' ) {
      FB.XFBML.parse();
   }
}


            </script>
```

(also in HTML doc)

```
    <div id= "fbsection"> 
                 <h1>Facebook</h1>  
                 <p class="centered"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/bluedolphinbodywork/">Like my Page</a> for the chance to be notified when I post special offers there, and please Invite your Facebook Friends, too! </p>

                     <div class="fb-page" style="max-width:300px; margin:auto;"
                         data-href="https://www.facebook.com/bluedolphinbodywork" 
                         data-tabs="timeline" 
                         data-small-header="false" 
                         data-adapt-container-width="true"
                         data-height="1000" 
                         data-width="300" 
                         data-hide-cover="false" 
                         data-show-facepile="true"> 
                            <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
                              <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/bluedolphinbodywork" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
                              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/bluedolphinbodywork">Blue Dolphin Bodywork</a>
                              </blockquote>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
```

Relevant snips from my stylesheet **bluedolphinbodywork.css**:

```
#fbsection {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width:480px;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    position: relative;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {

#fbsection {
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:250px;
    }

@media only screen and (min-width: 732px) {

#fbsection {
    max-width:300px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for all replies.

Comment: A working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/S3C_MM/yc56dm3g/) without any media queries.

Answer (score 1):

I customised the solution to suit my needs as I just needed to resize the width and simplified the solution as follows:

```
function resizeFBPlugin(){
    //getting parent box width
    var container_width = ($('.fb-column').width() - parseInt($('.fb-column').css('padding-left'))).toFixed(0);

    if (!isNaN(container_width)) {
        $(".fb-page").attr("data-width", container_width);
    }
    if (typeof FB !== 'undefined' ) {
        FB.XFBML.parse();
    }
}
```

Html Code. Ensure your widget is wrapped under the div with class fb-column or whatever you choose to name your class.

```
    <div class="fb-column">
      <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="true" data-width="500" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/">Facebook/a></blockquote></div>
    </div>
```

You can then run the function resizeFBPlugin on window load and resize. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

the code here:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
```

is a code for jQuery. $ is an alias for jQuery itself when it is loaded. On your site jQuery is not correctly loaded yet. You should add something like this to the head if you got it [locally from here](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/):

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

For more about the $ thing:
[How does jQuery achieve making $ an alias for the jQuery function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797956/how-does-jquery-achieve-making-an-alias-for-the-jquery-function)

You could also write it as:

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
```

After it is loaded correctly.

Various third party hosted jQuerys will work, see here: https://code.jquery.com/ (I'm not sure which version is the best but I think it likely 2.x would work)

For example:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Keep an eye on the console log for further Javascript errors and notices. Some may not be actual breaking errors, but in this case you would see that $ is not defined and that would prevent the main thing from loading.

Answer (score 0):

Saw your post on the original blog post. There is a typo in the sample code provided that will result in a Type error if not caught or you're unfamiliar with syntax. Here's what worked for me, with all script and styles embedded for convenience. I removed the header that they'd added for their purposes, but you can easily add that back in (just make sure to change `.fb-column-   header` to `.fb-column-header` in your styles).

Also, `YOURPAGE` was meant to be a placeholder, but it looks like someone actually has that URL, so apologies for the weird shirtless guy.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var CMSSpace = CMSSpace || {};
  </script>
  <style>
    .fb-column {
      height: 550px;
      min-height: 550px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2"></script>
  <div class="fb-column">
    <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/YOURPAGE" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">
      <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/YOURPAGE" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/YOURPAGE">YOUR PAGE NAME</a></blockquote>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        CMSSpace.changeFBPagePlugin()
      }, 500);
    });

    $(window).on('load', function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        CMSSpace.changeFBPagePlugin()
      }, 1500);
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    CMSSpace.changeFBPagePlugin = function() {
      //getting parent box width
      var container_width = (Number($('.fb-column').width()) - Number($('.fb-column').css('padding-left').replace("px", ""))).toFixed(0);
      //getting parent box height
      var container_height = (Number($('.fb-column').height()) - (Number(($('.fb-column').css('padding-top').replace("px", "") * 2)))).toFixed(0);
      if (!isNaN(container_width) && !isNaN(container_height)) {
        $(".fb-page").attr("data-width", container_width).attr("data-height", container_height);
      }
      if (typeof FB !== 'undefined') {
        FB.XFBML.parse();
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have adapted this into a simpler bit of code that will hopefully be helpful.

All you need to do is to integrate your Facebook feed as normal, add a class of `fb-container` to the parent div tag and ensure jQuery is loaded.

The code you need is:

```
//Make Facebook Feed Responsive 100% Height
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    setTimeout(function () { changeFBPagePlugin(); }, 500);
});

$(window).on('load', function () {
    setTimeout(function () { changeFBPagePlugin(); }, 1500);
});

changeFBPagePlugin = function () {
    var container_width = Number($('.fb-container').width()).toFixed(0);
    var container_height = Number($('.fb-container').height()).toFixed(0);
    if (!isNaN(container_width) && !isNaN(container_height)) {
        $(".fb-page").attr("data-width", container_width).attr("data-height", container_height);
    }
    if (typeof FB !== 'undefined') {
        FB.XFBML.parse();
    }
};
```

I am using this with a Bootstrap website with the feed inside a `col-md` column and it always fills the full height no matter the size.

Answer (score -2):

While it seems like it should be theoretically possible to do what you are trying to do, it was proving to be too much of a challenge for what I was up to tonight. By far it would be easier if your web design could keep the facebook plugin constant width, so you don't have to try to refresh it to make it responsive.